# AngularJS ng-view not loading

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I am working with AngularJS route for my website, but NG-VIEW does not load anything. I am just testing the "about" link. I want NG-VIEW to show `about.html`when I click "About me" from nav bar.

Here is `index.html`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/parallax.js-1.4.2/parallax.js"></script>

    <title>##</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="AgendaApp">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="topnav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/about">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/AgendaController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ScheduleController.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/schedules.js"></script>
```

and `app.js` is:

```
var app= angular.module("AgendaApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        controller: 'AgendaController',
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
    })
    .when('/detail', {
        controller: 'ScheduleController',
        templateUrl: 'views/schedule.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

and controller:

```
app.controller("AgendaController", ['$scope', 'schedules', function($scope, schedules) {
    schedules.success(function(data){
        $scope.schedules = data;
    });
}]);
```

my controller does not do anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#home" class="button">Home</a>
        <a href="#about" class="button">About</a>
        <a href="#detail" class="button">Detail</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/jQvDMefdjesh1fBeHYSF?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great now